# How to connecct mysql with two difffrent diffrent port through haproxy

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, haproxy, mysql-replication

I have 2 mysql server and one ha-proxy server mysql server pointed to haproxy server with diffirent diffrent port ( 3306 and 3307 ) . when i try to connect mysql server tohrough haproxy with port 3306 im abe to connect but when i try to connect mysql through haproxy with 3307 port unable to connect mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL listening to BOTH ports then simply leave the backend server port out of the HAProxy config i.e. let the client decide the end port to connect to.

OR if your MySQL is only listening on 3306 then force all the connections to go to that port by specifying it on the backend config.

If still stuck try posting your config.